# Cannot send FormData to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

Good day,

I'm trying to build basic file loading site but I just can't make it work.

There are no error messages, it just won't do it.

Here's my JS

```
var attachments = document.getElementById('files'); 
var file = new FormData();

for (i=0; i< attachments.files.length; i++){
    file.append('file[]', attachments.files[i]);
    console.log(attachments.files[i]);

}
console.log(file);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST','php/upload.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache');
request.send(file);
```

The HTML is like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="files" name="file[]" multiple="multiple"><br>
</form>
```

and the PHP is quite simple - **although** I never get the echo message,

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])&&!empty($_FILES['file'])){
echo 'got to through the if';
}
```

Any ideas on what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you first test your form a simple way, by uploading the files just using the submit button (i.e. no JavaScript). Does the upload work then?

Comment: Isn't the name of the file, 'file[]'?

Comment: I did checked it without the javascript and it was working properly.

Comment: also I've changed the name from file[] ->file and it didn't worked.

Comment: What console messages are you getting from `console.log(attachments.files[i]);` and `console.log(file);` ?

Comment: the attachment.file[i] console gives the information per file.

the console.log(file) gives the FormData.

They're both quite long, is there a specific parameter you wan't me to write down?